# Python: is it possible to start and stop a while loop from another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I am trying to start and stop a while loop within a thread from another thread. But no matter what I do I can't get it to work properly. I am actually able to stop a while loop in another thread, but then I am unable to start the while loop again. Is this even possible? In it's core it seems to be a simple question, but I have been unable to find a proper answer to it. Maybe I just have to rethink my code architecture? Or maybe there are other tools (for threading or otherwise) which I should use?

Here is try number 1, which can stop a while loop, but not start it again:

```
import threading
import time

first_time = True

def read_sensors():
     while run_event2.is_set():
         run_event2.wait()
         time.sleep(0.5)
         print("sensor read")
         
def back_end():
    global first_time
    while run_event.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        print("back-end")
        if first_time:
             first_time = False
             time.sleep(5)
             print("clear sensors")
             run_event2.clear()
             time.sleep(2)
             print("set sensors")
             run_event2.set()
             time.sleep(5)
             print("clear sensors")
             run_event2.clear()
             time.sleep(3)
             print("set sensors")
             run_event.set()

run_event = threading.Event()
run_event2 = threading.Event()

run_event.set()
run_event2.set()

t1 = threading.Thread(target = read_sensors)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = back_end)

t1.start()
time.sleep(.5)
t2.start()
time.sleep(5)

try:
 while 1:
     time.sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print("closing threads")
 run_event.clear()
 run_event2.clear()
 t1.join()
 t2.join()
 print("threads successfully closed")
```

Here is another code example where I am using a global variable to stop a while loop, but again I am unable to figure out how to start the while loop again.

```
import threading
import time

run_event2 = True
run_event = True

def read_sensors():
     global run_event2
     while run_event2:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("run_event2 value: {0}".format(run_event2)) 
          print("sensor read")

         
def back_end():
     global run_event
     global run_event2
     while run_event:
          time.sleep(1)
          print("back-end")
          time.sleep(5)
          run_event2 = False
          time.sleep(5)
          run_event2 = True

t1 = threading.Thread(target = read_sensors)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = back_end)

t1.start()
time.sleep(.5)
t2.start()
time.sleep(5)

try:
 while 1:
     time.sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print("closing threads")
 run_event2 = False
 run_event = False
 t1.join()
 t2.join()
 print("threads successfully closed")
```

Comment: Why can't you just start the thread again when you need it?

Comment: I think You could have a global variable that changes, so every loop You check it's state and change it from the other thread

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this type of an output?

[image]

If Yes please try calling one function within another, if not please manually compose an output that you would like to achieve. Like calling another fn when sensor is off
See the modified code for the above oupput

```
import threading
import time

run_event2 = True
run_event = True

def read_sensors():
    global run_event2
    
    while run_event2:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("run_event2 value: {0}".format(run_event2)) 
        print("sensor read")
        
        if run_event2 == False:
            back_end()

def back_end():
    
    global run_event
    global run_event2
    while run_event:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("back-end")
        time.sleep(5)
        run_event2 = False
        time.sleep(5)
        run_event2 = True
        read_sensors()

t1 = threading.Thread(target = read_sensors)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = back_end)

t1.start()
time.sleep(.5)
t2.start()
time.sleep(5)

try:
    while 1:
        time.sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("closing threads")
    run_event2 = False
    run_event = False
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print("threads successfully closed")
```